# Scope of star in regex

Tags: regex

I was reading a tutorial on PHP and came acros an example as follows:

```
p(hp)*
```

The tutorial says that this regex expression will mach any string containing a `p` followed by a sequence of zero or more occurrences of `php`.

I would think it is `p` followed by zero or more occurrences of `hp`, instead of `php`.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: You're correct. So either the tutorial was wrong or you misread it.

Comment: Got a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you got it from this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) **which is wrong**:

[image]

The **correct** possible matches for `p(hp)*`:

```
p
php
phphp
phphphp
phphphphp 
(...)
```

So it is p followed by zero or more of `hp`.

Since there is an error in the tutorial I suggest that you check for other documents as you might find some other uncorrect examples.
This proves there were no revision of the site.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that was the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As Meninx already detected the issue (un-revised site), I am adding little bit of more details regaiding use of * in Regular Expressions, as questions title is asking about "scope of star in regex".

There are two ways to use * in Regular Expressions:

1. Greedy Quantifier
2. Zero or more of something

**Greedy Quantifier**

Matches as many characters as possible after *str*.

```
/string.*a/
```

This **string will get matches greedely by a**bove regex.

**Zero or More Of**

```
at*
```

This string will get m**at**ches greedely by **a**bove regex.